# Pandas - Filtering out dates by day of week

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that contains dates along with day of the week. I am trying to filter out dates that fall on Monday or Tuesday.

Given below is the view of my Dataframe and what I have tried doing thus far:

```
date, day_of_week
1/1/2018, Monday
1/2/2018, Tuesday
1/3/2018, Wednesday
```

Expected Output:

```
date, day_of_week
1/1/2018, Monday
1/2/2018, Tuesday
```

I tried to do the below to achieve the output:

```
df.index.day_of_week < 2
```

But it returns

```
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'day_of_week'
```

Comment: df = df[(df["day_of_week"] != "Monday) & (df["day_of_week"] != "Tuesday")] ?

date and day_of_the_week are two separate columns I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[df.day_of_the_week.isin(['Monday', 'Tuesday'])]
```

Output:

```
   date  day_of_the_week
0  1/1/2018          Monday
1  1/2/2018         Tuesday
```